# Grails issue with linux mint

Tags: linux, grails, path, global-variables

i seem to have a problem running grails commands in terminal. i cant seem to run my grails commands when i am root but i can run them when i am logged as my user-name? i am using Linux mint 16.

So basically i cant run grails as root.I tried setting the path variable in /etc/profile but i still cant seem to run grails as root. It cant even find the path to my grails home variable however it can find my maven home & Java home path variables.Its just grails it cant seem to find as root.

i have the normal zip file extracted onto my download folder and running the grails install from there.

Comment: ok thanks i understand what you are saying.i would of thought that something was wrong as i coudnt run my apps as root and i dont have to chmod them everytime i run them.i guess my install is working fine then. Thanks

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to run anything in Grails as root? There's nothing Grails itself or any plugins that I know of that would do damage, but you would be running Gant scripts as root and be able to do anything, and very conveniently. I would consider this a feature that saved you a lot of stress and frustration, and don't try to use root.

Comment: Something _is_ probably wrong - technically this should work - but it's a dangerous thing to do, and never required. You might need to use su or sudo to change directory permissions/ownership or something similar, but you would do that and return to your regular account ASAP.